# Java: How do I print \\n in output?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have wanted to print \n in output by replacing `\r\n`:

I have written my code as such : `"John \r\n find".replaceAll("\r\n", "\\\\n"));`

But the output comes as such always:

```
John \n find
```

I wanted the output to be : `John \\n find`

Comment: Not 4 only 2 \ will be enough

Comment: use "John \r\n find".replaceAll("\r\n", "\\\\\\\\n")); as suggested by @Kayaman

Answer (score 0):

A **platform-independent** way of replacing the String `\r\n` with a new line separator would be:

```
String s = "John \r\n find".replaceAll("\r\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
System.out.println(s);
```

Output is (note that the blanks are kept, of course):

```
John
 find
```

In order to replace the blank characters as well use:

```
"John \r\n find".replaceAll(" \r\n ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```